# Where is the Yennie gauge useful in Gupta-Bleuer formalism (or QED in general)?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, commutator, gauge

Consider the Lagrangian of the Gupta-Bleuer formalism given by:
$$\mathcal{L}
=-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}
-\frac{1}{2\xi}(\partial A)^2.$$
I understand the necessity of the gauge fixing term: Without it, we would have $\Pi^\kappa=F^{\kappa 0}$ and therefore $\Pi^0=F^{00}=0$ due to the antisymmetry of the electromagnetic tensor, resulting in a contradiction with the commutator $[A^0(t,x),\Pi^0(t,x')]=i\delta^3(x-x')$ given by canonical quantization.

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing#R%CE%BE_gauges) of gauge fixing claims, that the *Feynman gauge* $\xi=1$ and the [*Yennie gauge*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_R._Yennie) $\xi=3$ are often the most useful ones for calculations. I understand this for the Feynman gauge, as for example the Gupta-Bleuer propagator is (compare with equation 4.95 [here](http://users.jyu.fi/%7Ehtpaukku/QFTI/Week8.pdf) for example) given by:
$$\widetilde{\Delta}_{\mathrm{GB},\mu\nu}(k)
=-\frac{i}{k^2+i\epsilon}\left(\eta_{\mu\nu}+(\xi-1)\frac{k_\mu k_\nu}{k^2}\right).$$
But where is the Yennie gauge useful? So far, I have not seen an example or found one. ("Yennie" is only mentioned in eight posts in total on PSE.) What is an example or a sketch of a derivation in Gupta-Bleuer formalism or QED, where the Yennie gauge is useful, or an explanation why it is special enough to deserve its own name?

Comment: Did you do your research before posting this question? Literally the first result upon Google searching “Yennie gauge” is the article https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003491680903309”. The very first paragraph of this paper answers your question.

Comment: @Prahar You can be assured I did do my research. (Given a seemingly simple question like this, it would be rather inappropriate not to do so.) But as my question indicates, I have searched mostly with "Gupta-Bleuer formalism" added or through scripts about it, that have only mentioned, but not explained the existence of the Yennie gauge - leaving me to assume, that there must be a deeper reason. Thank you for the link, the paper is not too long to not give it a full read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the answer to your question is probably found the easiest in the
[original article by Yennie, Frautschi and Suura](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003491661901518?via%3Dihub)
They found that the charge renormalization constant in QED is free of infrared divergencies in Yennie gauge (in the article it is shown in eq.(5.9)) to all orders.

Actually I am not aware of any other use of this specific gauge choice, but maybe another answer will give more insights on that.

Comment: Thank you! It seems like footnote 13 on page 430 about "the gauge, in which the renormalized photon propagator has the form $\delta_\nu^{\;\mu}/k^2$ for small $k^2$" is a simple answer, that doesn't even require the need to understand most of or all of the paper.